# Jenkins Android Build failed , gradlew build env: sh: No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jenkins, gradle

I am working on react-native project and trying to build android project on jenkins and getting error.

> [Gradle] - Launching build. [android] $
>   /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/projName/workspace/projName/android/gradlew
>   build env: sh: No such file or directory Build step 'Invoke Gradle
>   script' changed build result to FAILURE Build step 'Invoke Gradle
>   script' marked build as failure Archiving artifacts Finished: FAILURE

**Below is screen shot for invoke gradle script section**

[image: in root build script I took path from jenkins server where gradlew is present.]

**if I try with different path in "Root build script". 
I receive the following error.**

> [Gradle] - Launching build. FATAL:
>   /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/projName/workspace/projName/android/gradlew/gradlew:
>   Not a directory java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/projName/workspace/projName/android/gradlew/gradlew:
>   Not a directory   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setMode(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:238)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setPermissions(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:260)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2045)     at
>   hudson.FilePath._chmod(FilePath.java:1758)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.access$2900(FilePath.java:208)    at
>   hudson.FilePath$Chmod.invoke(FilePath.java:1741)  at
>   hudson.FilePath$Chmod.invoke(FilePath.java:1733)  at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1073)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1056)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.chmod(FilePath.java:1731)     at
>   hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.performTask(Gradle.java:226)     at
>   hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.perform(Gradle.java:152)     at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)  at
>   hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) Archiving artifacts
>   Finished: FAILURE

I tried multiple ways but no success.

1. By Changing different paths
2. uncheck "Make gradlew executable"
3. using "invoke gradle method"

Comment: Does the /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/projName/workspace/projName/android/gradlew folder exists?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh /Users/administrator/.jenkins/jobs/projName/workspace/projName/android/

above folder exists.
and gradlew exists inside the android folder

Comment: @BalwinderSingh any suggestion if I am doing anything wrong here ?